# Polars - Replace value in column with fewer than X unique values a different specific value

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I'm trying to rewrite a `pandas` pipeline using `polars`. I have columns with a lot of unique categories, I want to replace all the categories that have less than X number of ocurrences with a specific value (in this case replacing categories that appear less than 50 times with the string "other")

- pandas:

```py
uniques = df["a"].value_counts()
df.loc[~df["a"].isin(uniques[uniques > 50].index), "a"] = "other"
```

- My attempt with polars:

```py
df = df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col("a").unique_counts() < 50).then("other").otherwise(pl.col("a")).alias("a"))
```

I've tried multiple variations of this code but I get either an error or a result I wasn't expecting.

I haven't found anything anywhere about this specific use case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to count items is `.count().over(col)` i.e. a [window function](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/window/)

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": ["a", "b", "c", "a"], "b": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df.with_columns(count = pl.count("a").over("a"))
```

```py
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ count │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ u32   │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 2     │
│ b   ┆ 2   ┆ 1     │
│ c   ┆ 3   ┆ 1     │
│ a   ┆ 4   ┆ 2     │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

This can be combined with `.when().then()`

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.count("a").over("a") > 1)
      .then("a")
      .otherwise(pl.lit("other"))
)
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌───────┬─────┐
│ a     ┆ b   │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ a     ┆ 1   │
│ other ┆ 2   │
│ other ┆ 3   │
│ a     ┆ 4   │
└───────┴─────┘
```

Comment: good one. only comment, in `df.with_columns(pl.col("a").count().over("a"))` if you like, give that column an alias so that the original 'a' stays intact otherwise it could be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible all in one expression, because `value_counts` and `unique_counts` result in a DataFrame / column / expression of different height than `a`.

Here's one way to do it with `with_context`, combining multiple DataFrames into one query execution plan, provided that they are lazy:

```py
# get the column as a Series, then Series.value_counts()
# returns a 2-column DataFrame with the counts.
df_vc = df.get_column('a').value_counts().lazy()

# filter the value_counts DataFrame
# and rename the appropriate column
# so it can be used in the query execution plan.
df.lazy().with_context(
    df_vc.filter(pl.col("counts") < 50).select(other="a")
).with_columns(
    a=pl.when(pl.col("a").is_in(pl.col("other")))
    .then("other")
    .otherwise(pl.col("a"))
).collect()
```